# Moved OS hdd to USB enclosure, how can I make it boot?

Tags: boot, usb, external-hard-drive, windows-10

I had a Windows 10 installation in my laptop. I got a new SSD for it so I took out the old HDD and put it in a USB enclosure.

The hard disk works fine and great, better than I thought it would on USB (yay for USB 3.0). However, it won't boot from the USB.

Is there any way I can boot my old OS too via USB?

Comment: @DavidPostill: are the issues and solutions for Win 10 the same as for XP?

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not sure. That's why the comment says possible duplication.

Comment: Suggesting a possible duplicate in a comment is fine, but let's not vote to close unless we know it's applicable.